# Extract string containing a word from an Excel cell with hundred of strings

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel workbook, in column A each cell contains all URLs of *a site* (this means hundreds of URLs in one cell).

Among all the URLs within a single cell I want to extract only the URL that contains the word **contact**

For example:

Cell A1: `http://examplesite.com/index.html; http://examplesite.com/login.php; http://examplesite.com/contact.html; http://examplesite.com/about.html`

Cell A2: `http://hello.publish.com/alumni; http://hello.publish.com/contact-us; http://hello.publish.com/sitemap; http://hellopublish.com/projects`

And so on

I woluld like to have this output on Column B

Cell B1:  `http://examplesite.com/contact.html`

Cell B2:  `http://hello.publish.com/contact-us`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following **U**ser **D**efined **F**unction *(UDF)*:

```
Public Function FindContact(inpt As String) As String
   ary = Split(inpt, "; ")
   For Each a In ary
      If InStr(1, a, "contact") > 0 Then
         FindContact = a
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next a
   FindContact = ""
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=FindContact(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: UDF above works perfectly! Thankyou so very much.

Answer (score -1):

Since all of your data is going down vertically, the command for you is the `VLookup` command. First in the B column set up an identifier for each of the URL starting from 1 and going on until the end. Do this by dragging the black dot at the corner all the way down until the end URL is met. example: `VLookup("contact",$A1:$B13,2,TRUE)`.