# Extract all URLs and emails from a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel workbook, in column A each cell contains lot of text and some URLs and emails (all this in one cell).

Among all the text within a single cell I want to extract all URLs and emails.

For example:

Cell A1: Text Text Hello http://examplesite.com/index.html hello friend  examplesite.com  who frnd@example.com

Cell A2: Text2 Text2 Hello2  fresh.com  who frnd2@fresh.com

And so on

I would like to have this output in column B

Cell B1: http://examplesite.com/index.html,examplesite.com,frnd@example.com

Cell B2:  fresh.com,frnd2@fresh.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, this isn't really a task Excel is suited for. Unless they've improved it dramatically in the most recent release, Excel's text manipulation capabilities are... weak. If I was faced with this, I'd export the data to a csv file then use a perl script to extract everything you want extracted, write it to a new csv, and import that.

Comment: Excel is indeed capable of doing what I have requested for. 
I posted a similar request some time ago and a nice person responded, below is the link for reference...

http://superuser.com/questions/973783/extract-string-containing-a-word-from-an-excel-cell-with-hundred-of-strings